# How to rearrange arrays

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I'm doing code in php and I'm stuck at one point If you know any solution then please give me answer.What I have an array is below :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Client] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 64
                            [firstname] => abc
                            [lastname] => def
                            [email] => abc@gmail.com
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Client] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 109
                            [firstname] => Sandip
                            [lastname] => Shah
                            [email] => abc223@gmail.com
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Client] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 120
                            [firstname] => Vandana
                            [lastname] => Mathur
                            [email] => v@gmail.com
                        )

                )


        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Client] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 113
                            [firstname] => Raj
                            [lastname] => Kumar
                            [email] => raj@gmail.com
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Now What I want the final array is below:
Is there possible to make like below way with using array php functions ?

```
Array
(
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Client] => Array
                        (
                                [id] => 64
                                [firstname] => abc
                                [lastname] => def
                                [email] => abc@gmail.com
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Client] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 109
                            [firstname] => Sandip
                            [lastname] => Shah
                            [email] => abc223@gmail.com
                        )

                )


            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Client] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 120
                            [firstname] => Vandana
                            [lastname] => Mathur
                            [email] => v@gmail.com
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Client] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 113
                            [firstname] => Raj
                            [lastname] => Kumar
                            [email] => raj@gmail.com
                        )

                )

)
```

Comment: What have you tried? [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge) will append for numerical indexes

Comment: with the newest version of php you could use argument unpacking with array merge like  array_merge(..$yourArray) to remove 1 level of the array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you just want to merge all the arrays of depth 2?

It's simple: expand the big array (via `call_user_func_array`) and merge its contents:

```
$newArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```